# how to align name label font to left in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

how to align name label font to left side, iam using reactjs

```
const inputs = [
    {
      type:'text',
      label: "Name",
      name:'name',
      isVisible: true,
      defaultValue: null,
      validate:{
        required: {value: true, errorMessage:"Name is required"}
      },
}
]
```

Comment: how do you render the inputs array

Comment: Can you show your jsx code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)